# MASM32. Cреднее арифметическое

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Написал код для нахождения среднего арифметического числа без знака, но ollydbg выдает мне ошибку [image: Ошибка], не могу понять в чем проблема, если кто то подскажет буду благодарен.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
includelib kernel32.lib
ExitProcess PROTO, :DWORD

.data
inpdd dd 4, -13, 2, 5
sum dd ?
res dd ?

.code
Winmain PROC
mov eax, inpdd ; load the array into EAX
mov ecx, 0

; loop through the array and sum up the values
sum_loop:
add ecx, [eax]
add eax, 4
loop sum_loop

mov sum, ecx ; save the sum as sum
mov eax, sum
mov ebx, 4
cdq ; sign-extend EAX into EDX
div ebx ; divide sum by 4

mov res, eax ; save the result in res

push 0
call ExitProcess

Winmain endp
end winmain
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! ошибка в первой строчке («Подскажите, не могу найти ошибку в коде.»): см. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Где именно ошибка в первой строчке? Там же все в норме

Comment: ошибка в строчке «Подскажите, не могу найти ошибку в коде». в чём именно ошибка, можно узнать, пройдя по приведённой [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: А данных сколько и где они описаны? Там похоже ошибка выхода за память процесса.

Comment: inpdd dd 4, -13, 2, 5

Comment: Ну, судя по ошибке `access violation`,  адрес `006F5000` - это уже видимо за границей где-то и туда лазить нельзя. Как оно туда лезет и почему - это вы разбирайтесь, я ассемблер 25 лет в руках не держал. )

Comment: Стоп, а где выход из цикла суммирования то? ))  Или я слепой, или "русская шутка - выхода нет" ))

Comment: Оператор loop уменьшает значение ecx на 1, сравнивает с 0, и если 0, то выходит из цикла. А вы в цикле значение в ecx наоборот увеличиваете.

Comment: @insolor Так у него в `ecx` сумма копится. А `loop` по какому-то условию прервётся или нужно в явном виде переменную-счётчик циклов проверять? P.S. А, понятно - и сумма и счётчик в одном регистре ))

Comment: @CrazyElf loop использует ecx как счетчик итераций. Сумму нужно в другом регистре накапливать.

Comment: Либо заменить loop на что-то типа `cmp eax, inpdd + 4 * 4` `jl sum_loop`, чтобы один и тот же регистр использовался и для адресации, и для проверки границ массива.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что для операции `loop` регистр `ecx` задает количество итераций. `loop` уменьшает значение `ecx` на 1, проверяет результат: если 0, то выходит из цикла, если не ноль, то переходит по указанной метке (на начало цикла). Т.е. loop можно представить как:

```
dec ecx
jnz sum_loop
```

А вы `ecx` используете для хранения суммы, в цикле его наоборот увеличиваете, в итоге выход из цикла не происходит, и вылетает из-за того что происходит попытка чтения за границами секции `.data`.

Решение - использовать какой-то другой регистр для накопления суммы, а в `ecx` указать размер обрабатываемого массива:

```
mov eax, inpdd ; адрес начала массива
mov edx, 0 ; здесь будет накапливаться сумма
mov ecx, 4 ; цикл должен выполниться 4 раза

; loop through the array and sum up the values
sum_loop:
add edx, [eax]
add eax, 4
loop sum_loop

mov sum, edx
```